# Shell Script on iMac no longer working with High Sierra

Tags: python, bash, cgi

I recently upgraded my iMac 27” (mid-2011) from Yosemite to High Sierra and I am struggling to get back some functionality that I had working previously!

To briefly explain… First of all, I grab local weather data from weather underground using some Python scripts on a Raspberry pi3. These scripts also massage the data and then create and store an XML file on the pi. I also, on the pi, run a http server that looks for calls.

On an iPad, using iRule, I have a button that is called ‘Weather Forecast’. When this button is pressed it triggers a network resource on my ISY994i (Insteon) controller that, in turn, makes a call to the http server on the pi sending it a parameter. When the pi receives the call and validates the parameter, it runs another Python script (on the pi) that takes the data in the previously created XML file and puts it into a proper format for the next step. Finally, that script sends GET requests to the iMac, through Apache2, to read the weather forecast out loud.

This was working very well on Yosemite but now that I have upgraded the **saying** part is not working!

I have 3 shell scripts on the iMac that are called, from the pi, in this process…

**saysomethinghttp9a.sh** This is the first script called which reads the current volume level and stores it in a local file (on the iMac); then it changes the volume level to an acceptable volume (I use 18);

```
!/bin/bash
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n"

PHRASE=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*phrase=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/+/ /g" | sed "s/%20/ /g"`

cat << junk
<html>
<head>
<title>
saying
</title>
</head>
<body>
junk

currVol=$(osascript -e "get volume settings")

echo "Current Volume Setting = $currVol"

var1=$( echo $currVol | cut -d":" -f1 )
var2=$( echo $currVol | cut -d":" -f2 )
origVol=$( echo $var2 | cut -d"," -f1 )
echo $origVol
parm="set volume output volume $origVol"
echo $parm

destfile="/Users/Sarah/Sound_Volume/Volume1.txt"
echo $parm > $destfile

osascript -e "set volume output volume 18"

cat << junk
</body>
</html>
junk
```

**saysomethinghttp9.sh** After the volume level has been set, this script does the ‘say’ part based upon what is sent from the pi. The pi calls this script and sends a parameter, which is the words I want said. This call is repeated several times for the intro, date, time, weather forecast and closing; and

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n"

PHRASE=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*phrase=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/+/ /g" | sed "s/%20/ /g"`

cat << junk
<html>
<head>
<title>
saying
</title>
</head>
<body>
junk

say "Hey There"

cat << junk
</body>
</html>
junk
```

**saysomethinghttp9b.sh**  Finally this last script is called, which reads the original volume from the file created in the first step and then resets the volume to that level.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n"

cat << junk
<html>
<head>
<title>
saying
</title>
</head>
<body>
junk

file="/Users/Sarah/Sound_Volume/Volume1.txt"
echo $file
read -d $'\x04' parm < "$file"
echo $parm

osascript -e "$parm"

cat << junk
</body>
</html>
junk
```

(*note that I go through the steps to adjust the volume because the volume for music, from iTunes, is much too loud for the ‘say’ commands*)

In trying to figure out what is wrong I have tried numerous things:

- I edited the script saysomethinghttp9.sh to eliminate the ‘say’ of a parameter passed to it and simply put in the line say “Hey there” (*note that the code above is the edited version*)
- I then opened up a terminal session on the iMac and issued the commands from there...

  - ./saysomethinghttp9a.sh
  - ./saysomethinghttp9.sh
  - ./saysomethinghttp9b.sh

All 3 scripts worked when called from the terminal so that wasn’t the problem.

To debug the calls to the iMac, I simplified the process by eliminating the iPad, the pi and the ISY994i from the process. Instead, I have been trying to make the calls to the iMac from a PC on the same network using a browser.

- http://10.0.1.11/cgi-bin/saysomethinghttp9a.sh
- http://10.0.1.11/cgi-bin/saysomethinghttp9.sh
- http://10.0.1.11/cgi-bin/saysomethinghttp9a.sh

The result from running the scripts directly from the browser, on the PC, was that script **saysomethinghttp9a.sh** and **saysomethinghttp9b.sh** worked but **saysomethinghttp9.sh** did not!

Here are the Access and Error log entries from the iMac after trying the calls from the browser on the PC…

**Access Log**

```
10.0.1.195 - - [18/Dec/2017:21:33:30 -0500] "GET /cgi-bin/saysomethinghttp9a.sh HTTP/1.1" 200 197

10.0.1.195 - - [18/Dec/2017:21:34:04 -0500] "-" 408 -

10.0.1.195 - - [18/Dec/2017:21:33:44 -0500] "GET /cgi-bin/saysomethinghttp9.sh HTTP/1.1" 200 53

10.0.1.195 - - [18/Dec/2017:21:33:49 -0500] "GET /cgi-bin/saysomethinghttp9.sh HTTP/1.1" 200 53

10.0.1.195 - - [18/Dec/2017:21:35:05 -0500] "GET /cgi-bin/saysomethinghttp9b.sh HTTP/1.1" 200 135
```

**Error Log**

```
[Mon Dec 18 21:34:44.356130 2017] [cgi:warn] [pid 29997] [client 10.0.1.195:60109] AH01220: Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/saysomethinghttp9.sh

[Mon Dec 18 21:34:44.356519 2017] [core:error] [pid 29997] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.0.1.195:60109] AH00574: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed

[Mon Dec 18 21:34:49.949284 2017] [cgi:warn] [pid 29575] [client 10.0.1.195:60107] AH01220: Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/saysomethinghttp9.sh

[Mon Dec 18 21:34:49.949652 2017] [core:error] [pid 29575] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.0.1.195:60107] AH00574: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed
```

For full disclosure, my programming experience is relatively limited. I often piece things together using examples that I find online.

I do not know how to interpret the errors noted above! The only information I could find related to "The timeout specified has expired" was related to situations where a lot of data was being dealt with! In my case, there is very little data being processed!

I would appreciate some help or direction on how to proceed.

**Edit:**

After reading the comments from Mark Setchell, I added into my script the '/usr/bin/id' and ran the script first in the terminal and saw that user name was correct. Then I ran the same script from the other PC and saw that the user name was '_www'! So I then edited the httpd.conf (apache2) file and changed the  section include **User Sarah** and **Group staff**. However this did not correct the problem!

Next I read up on how to 'use su to become that user and try the script'. Through the readings I kept finding suggestions to use sudo instead and finally found a suggestion to edit the sudoers file. So I did this using the command **sudo visudo**. Then I added in the following line

**Sarah   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL**

Then I tried running the script from the PC once again however this time the script ran and is **saying** again!

Comment: Try making sure you have the PATH set correctly at the second line of each script to include all the binaries you call, e.g. `say`, `osascript` so that would be `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: You can get the current volume more simply by telling `awk` to get the 3rd field of the `osascript` command while treating spaces, colons and commas as field separators like this `vol=$(osascript -e "get volume settings" | awk -F'[ :,]' '{print $3}')`

Comment: Mark... I appreciate your comments. I added your PATH line into the scripts but the results are the same - 2 scripts work but the one doing the 'say' does not! With respect to your other suggestion to simplify getting the current volume... thanks, I will try that when I have time.

Comment: Can you find the userid that the script runs as, e.g. by running `/usr/bin/id` in the script or by checking your Apache config files. Then use `su` to become that user and try the script (or just `say "hi"`) as that user and see if it works. It may be a permissions thing as to who can run `say` or something to do with not having a terminal when running under Apache.

Comment: Well done - thank you for sharing. You can put your results as an answer for all to see, and you can also accept it even though it's your own.

Comment: How do I "put your results as an answer for all to see" and accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the comments from Mark Setchell, I added into my script the '/usr/bin/id' and ran the script first in the terminal and saw that user name was correct. Then I ran the same script from the other PC and saw that the user name was '_www'! So I then edited the httpd.conf (apache2) file and changed the section include User Sarah and Group staff. However this did not correct the problem!

Next I read up on how to 'use su to become that user and try the script'. Through the readings I kept finding suggestions to use sudo instead and finally found a suggestion to edit the sudoers file. So I did this using the command ***sudo visudo***. Then I added in the following line

**Sarah ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL**

Then I tried running the script from the PC once again however this time the script ran and is **saying** again!

Comment: make your working admin user can sudo with no password? not sound a good idea... this makes anyone could control your system.